# C# - ASP.NET MVC - Convert a List of object , to a List of string, to use in a Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I have that typed List:

```
IEnumerable<Resource> ResourceAuthorizedForLoggedUser= resourceAuthorizer.FindAll();
```

First a try this, but didn't work:

```
var authorizations= ResourceAuthorizedForLoggedUser.Select(x => x.Id).ToString();
```

And I need to put inside that Session:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Authorized_List"] = authorizations;
```

To be able to access this data in the base controller

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   public static List<string> authorizations { get { return Getauthorizations(); } }

   private static List<string> Getauthorizations()
   {
      List<string> authorizationsList = (List<string>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Authorized_List"];
      return authorizationsList != null && authorizationsList.Any() ? authorizationsList : new List<string>();
   }
}
```

And in the end, I get the following error at `Getauthorizations` method:

> It is not possible to convert an object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [System.String]'

Any ideas how I can convert that list?

Comment: `ToList()` rather than `ToString()` when setting the session variable.

Comment: `ResourceAuthorizedForLoggedUser.Select(x => x.Id)` that will only get one user more than likely, why make it a list? Set a breakpoint on `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Authorized_List"] = authorizations;` what type is `authorizations`, it's not what you think it is.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I would have thought `resourceAuthorizer.FindAll()` could return more than one object.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay it does, but look at `ResourceAuthorizedForLoggedUser.Select(x => x.Id).ToString()`... that's not going to give a collection :)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yes, hence my initial comment; it should likely be `.Select(x => x.Id).ToList()`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay correct, but should that list have possibly the same person more than once with the same id; I would hope not. I'm not seeing the reason for even a collection the OP is wanting.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The type of `ResourceAuthorizedForLoggedUser` is `IEnumerable<Resource>`. So `Resource.Id` is being selected. OP is trying to store a list of `Resource.Ids` in session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write your code as follows:

1. First, you get your colletion of type Resource:

> ```
>  IEnumerable<Resource> ResourceAuthorizedForLoggedUser=
>  resourceAuthorizer.FindAll();
> ```

2. Then you save the list of Ids (I assume they are strings)

> ```
>  List<string> authorizations=
>  ResourceAuthorizedForLoggedUser.Select(x=> x.Id).ToList();
> ```

3. Save that in the session variable:

> ```
>  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Authorized_List"] =
>  authorizations;
> ```

4. Read it back from Session:

> ```
> public class BaseController : Controller
>      {
>         public static List<string> authorizations { get { return Getauthorizations(); } }
>
>
>    private static List<string> Getauthorizations()
>    {
>       List<string> authorizationsList = (List<string>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Authorized_List"];
>       return authorizationsList != null && authorizationsList.Any() ? authorizationsList : new List<string>();
>    }
> }`enter code here`
> ```